# How to send email to user when custom post type is approved in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to send a confirmation email to user when his/ her custom post type is approved in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Use this  [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-author-on-publish/)  or learn from its code.